# What are the optimal settings for a video that will be played on a Galaxy Tab 10.1?

Tags: video, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

What are the best size, compression settings, and format for making video for playback on a Galaxy Tab 10.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Video

The Galaxy Tab 10.1 will work best with MP4 files (H.264 encoding) at 720p (1280x720). Do *not* use Entropy Coding. I'm noticing a few problems with it; it could be the video / my setup though and not the device itself.

Use a constant bitrate at a reasonable quality level (RF:20 should be good, or around 1000kbps). Maximum B-Frames should be set to 0, and Reference frames to 4 or 5.

## Audio

As far as audio goes you should be fine with most anything; a samplerate of 48 and a bitrate of 160 should be good. Make sure to downmix to stereo. AAC is probably you best bet for the codec.

### Summary

More information can be found [here](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-20090725-285/how-to-encode-movies-to-play-on-your-galaxy-tab-10.1/) and [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1060825) (though you might want to experiment a bit with some of the advanced settings if you feel that you need them—Probably not a big deal though).

**Audio:** AAC with Bitrate of 160, Samplerate of 48; downmix to stereo
**Video:** H.264 in an MP4 wrapper at 720p (1280x720) at a constant bit rate

Comment: **Do not force resolution to 1280x720!** Always keep the aspect ratio!

Comment: @Richard Borcsik: Well yah; I wasn't suggesting he resize all of his videos to 1280x720; but assuming 16:9 that's what will look best. Just recommended dimensions.

Comment: I didn't think that you did, just mentioned it because you didn't, so people don't try to do so.

Comment: Great answer! One question: I don't use Handbrake, so I don't know what RF:20 means in terms of bitrate. Can you provide an actual bitrate number that would be ideal?

Comment: Thanks; I mentioned Handbrake because that seems to be the standard thing that most people use, but RF isn't specific to it. RF actually corresponds to the compression level, not the bitrate (my answer sounded a bit ambiguous, sorry). RF19 or 20 is about where a DVD is, which is why you'll see that number thrown around a lot. If you have to set bitrate separately, don't skimp. The Galaxy Tab will do fine with higher bitrate video (most things will set it automatically based on the compression level and the original source bitrate).

Comment: Oops, forgot to include the actual bitrate... 1000kbps should be a safe upper limit, and maybe more than you'll need. Answer updated.

Comment: Tells me everything I needed to know. Thanks very much! A bounty of 50 points for you! :)

Comment: Glad I could be of service

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1060825) on XDA-Developers forums.  There's a good discussion with presets for Handbrake (conversion software) that should work well for GTab 10.1.

Basic settings are as follows:
**Video**: H.264 codec, MP4 container, picture width 1200, constant quality with RF:20, loose anamorphic with modulus 16.
**Audio**: AAC format, 128 bitrate.

Comment: +1 for the Handbrake how-to, that's the path I'd choose.

Comment: While there's probably too much information in that thread to include it all here, if that link fails to work this answer is absolutely useless. Can you at least include some of the useful information here?